# Create custom pathbrowser predicate in AEM 6.2

Tags: java, maven, osgi, aem

I'm trying to implement custom OSGI service predicate for pathbrowser. If somebody have any idea what is wrong with this code :) There is exception below. Maybe it is something with the @Component or dependency

```
<path jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
      sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
      fieldDescription="List item link" 
      fieldLabel="List Item link"
      name="./path"
      predicate="predicate"
      rootPath="/content">
</path>
```

Predicate implementation:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;

import com.day.cq.commons.predicate.AbstractResourcePredicate;
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page;

@Component(label = "Content-page Predicate", description = "This predicate is used to restricted to allow selection of pages that have template content-page")
@Service(value = Predicate.class)
@Properties({
     @Property(label = "Predicate Name", name = "predicate.name", value = "predicate", propertyPrivate = true) })
public class ContentPagePredicate extends AbstractResourcePredicate {

    private static final String CQ_TEMPLATE_CONTENT = "/conf/xxx-lab/settings/wcm/templates/content-page";

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Resource resource) {
        if (null != resource) {
            if (!resource.getResourceType().equals("cq:Page")) {
                return false;
            }
            Page page = resource.adaptTo(Page.class);

            return page.getTemplate().getName().equals(CQ_TEMPLATE_CONTENT);

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Maven build output:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project SomethingDemo.core: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr: java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return
[ERROR] Exception Details:
[ERROR] Location:
[ERROR] com/day/cq/commons/predicate/AbstractNodePredicate.<init>()V @1: return
[ERROR] Reason:
[ERROR] Error exists in the bytecode
[ERROR] Bytecode:
[ERROR] 0x0000000: 2ab1
```

Comment: what happen if you extends AbstractNodePredicate instead of AbstractResourcePredicate?

Answer (score 2):

The error you see can happen when you extend a class from the AEM API that's annotated with SCR annotations (used to generate OSGi bundle descriptors) and, at the same time, obfuscated in the Uber Jar you're using.

You can find an unobfuscated Uber Jar for the AEM version you're using in [Adobe's public Maven repository](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/adobe/aem/uber-jar/).

If you represent a customer or a partner, you should also be able to download one from the help site https://daycare.day.com/home/products/uberjar.html

If your project is using a repository that already has the unobfuscated Jar, it should be as simple as changing the dependency.

For example, in a project using the AEM 6.2 Uber Jar with obfuscated classes

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
    <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <classifier>obfuscated-apis</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Just change the classifier to get an unobfuscated version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
    <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <classifier>apis</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Check out this [Github issue](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/lazybones-aem-templates/issues/8) for a wider discussion on a very similar problem.

You may also find this [Adobe Help Forum thread](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.1.html/forum__qlk9-hi_i_have_beena.html) interesting,
although it pertains to a beta version.

Comment: FWIW, unobfuscated uber jars are now available for everyone. See https://daycare.day.com/home/products/uberjar.html

Comment: @i.net good to know. However, I can see that the link you posted is password-protected. Looks like basic HTTP authentication but there's no indication as to what credentials should be used. Does this use one's Adobe ID?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that and can't edit comment now (not enough rep?)... Basically you don't need to request for a UberJar if you are a customer because that link allows you to download it (assuming you have access to it). In case you don't have access, the following link on Adobe's public repo will get you the unobfuscated jar files: https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/adobe/aem/uber-jar/6.2.0/uber-jar-6.2.0-apis.jar You will also find obfuscated version in same folder. Also, these are available for other versions too.

Comment: @i.net that's not a rep thing. Comments are only editable for a limited amount of time (in the order of several minutes, can't remember the exact number). Updated my answer to include the links you posted. Thanks.

Comment: just remove obfuscated

Answer (score 1):

Just try to implement `org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate`.

Also: `resource.getResourceType().equals("cq:Page")` will never be `true`, as `cq:Page` is the resource's `jcr:pimaryType`. `page.getTemplate()` does not work on publish:

```
public booean evaluate(Resource resource) {
    if (null == resource) return false;
    final ValueMap map = resource.getValueMap();
    return "cq:Page".equals(map.get("jcr:primaryType", "")
            && CQ_TEMPLATE_CONTENT.equals(map.get("cq:template", "")
}
```